# Arch linux missing icons in xfce4-settings-manager?

Tags: arch-linux, xfce

I've recently installed XFCE4 in an Arch Linux VM, including the elementary icon theme

```
pacman -S xfce4 elementary-icon-theme
```

When I open xfce4-settings-manager, several icons are missing

[image]

Any ideas?

FYI: I'm on Mac OS with retina screen, so I had to change the DPI to `180`, it shouldn't be related to this issue

Comment: Try installing `gnome-icon-theme` and restart X11 to see if helps. Alternatively, install `lxappearance` and force the selection of a specific icon theme of your choice (elementary, maybe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the projects github: "Not a Universal Icon Set" https://github.com/elementary/icons

You will need to install a theme with a complete icon set as fallback for the missing icons.

As suggested you probably want to install gnome-icon-theme as it'd be the quickest solution. But there are attempts at a more complete icon set here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/elementary-xfce-icons